# Regex: match all special characters but not *

Tags: regex

Yet another question about a regex.

I'm trying to match all special characters, except '*'.

So if I match my regex against:

```
John%%%* dadidou
```

I should get:

```
John* dadidou
```

Here: [How to match with regex all special chars except "-" in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727097/how-to-match-with-regex-all-special-chars-except-in-php)

The accepted answer advices to use (if I want to exclude '-'):

```
[^\w-]
```

But doesn't that mean: "NOT a special character, NOT -", which is a bit redundant ?

Comment: Try `[a-zA-Z0-9*\s]+`

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: `\w` is not a wildcard for special characters, it's for *word* characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you really want is this regex for matching:

```
[^\w\s*]+
```

Replace it by empty string.

Which means match 1 or more of any character that is:

1. Not a word character [AND]
2. Not a whitespace [AND]
3. Not a literal `*`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fX7nC6/1)

Comment: `\w` will match `_`(_special character_) too. `[^A-Za-z0-9\s*]+`

Comment: Yes it matches `_` as well but not sure if OP wants to remove `_` also or keep it

Comment: Just fyi if OP wants to remove `_` as well then use: [`_|[^\w\s*]+`](https://regex101.com/r/fX7nC6/2) regex

Comment: Yes, I also want to remove _. Why isn't it matched by the special characters condition btw ?

Comment: `\w` does not match special characters, it matches *word* characters. Somehow you keep confusing these two. Because of the negation `^` it matches "not-word characters". The definition of what set "word characters" match can be found on sites describing regular expressions (with the usual caveat that it depends on the implementation).

Answer (score 2):

When you define a *negative* character class, you are really inverting it.

What does that mean ?

A positive character class implicitly *OR*'s it's contents.

When you negate a class, you implicitly *AND* it's contents.

So, `[\w-]` means `word OR dash`,
the inverse, `[^\w-]` means `not word AND not dash`.

A negative word for instance, `[^\w]` would match a dash `-`.
So, to not match it, you have to add a `not dash` as well.

A C analogy would be

existing `(varA || varB)`
inverted `(!varA && !varB)`

where inverting changes the Boolean of each of the components.

*Basically a negative class changes the Boolean of each of its components,

so the implicit **OR** becomes an implicit **AND** and the components characters

(or expressions) are **negated**.*

---

What will really bake your noodle later on is when you see something like
`[^\S\r\n]`

This translates to `NOT-NOT-Whitespace` *and* `NOT-cr` *and* `NOT-lf`
which reduces to matching all whitespace *except* CR,LF