# Combine regex character classes

Tags: php, regex

Regex pattern `/[^[:ascii:]]+/ui` will match one or more non-ascii characters.

Regex pattern `/[\p{L}]+/ui` will match one or more characters in unicode 'letter' class.

I can't figure out a way how to match one or more characters that are in unicode 'letter' class AND are not ascii characters.

Comment: You can apply this pattern: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9727332/367456

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negated character class like this:

```
[^\P{L}[:ascii:]]+
```

[RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/qTg1qE/2)

This will match 1+ of any character that is not an ASCII and not matched by `\P{L}` (inverse of `\p{L}`)

---

Alternatively, you can use negative lookahead in a non-capture group:

```bash
(?:(?![[:ascii:]])\p{L})+
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/qTg1qE/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```php
[^\P{L}A-Za-z]+
```

It matches any Unicode letter that is not equal to ASCII letter.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9JaPCr/1).

In PHP, you should use the `u` flag to make it work correctly with Unicode strings:

```php
$regex = '/[^\P{L}A-Za-z]+/u';
```